# Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on IA 32-bit platform

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

All. 
There is an error that I met when I try the first "hello world" Android App with VisualStudio Community 2017 , I can't open the Main.xaml file within Vs 2017. And I try to find solution from stackoverflow.com, yes, there are some question like "Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on IA 32-bit platform", but what I met is a little different. So what can I do?

More information:
1. OS in my laptop is 32-bit Win7;
2. There are someting wrong during the installation of "Mobile Development With .net", and there is the unique module I have installed with VS 2017.
can not download “AndroidNDK_R13B,version=13.1.5,chip=x86” from “https: //go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=833503”;
can not download “https: //go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=841570” from “AndroidEmulator_API23V2,version=1.0.28” ;
3. The detailed information about the exception is: (When I double clicked on the Main.Xaml file)

[er](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Gjb.jpg)

```
ava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Hargendas\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidDesigner3976194309885156563.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at mono.android.JniHelper.loadEmbeddedJniLibrary(JniHelper.java:28)
at mono.android.D3DImageFactory.<clinit>(D3DImageFactory.java:14)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.initializePlatformSpecific(DesignerSession.java:86)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.<init>(DesignerSession.java:75)
at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:382)
at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)
at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have move the "C:\Program Files\Android" folder to "D:\Program Files\Android" and "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\packages" to "D:\Program Files\VS2017SDK", and build symbol link with these folder by the "mklink" operation.
Is it any effect with the error? And where did the temporary "AndroedDesigner3976194309885156563.dll" made from? and everytime I try to open the Main.xaml, the temporary file with error is different, How to solve the problem?

I had try to install a 64-bit JRE, but my OS is 32-bit, it would not be installed successfully. So Do I have to upgrade My laptop to 64-bit Win10?

Thanks.

Comment: What microprocessor do you have and is it a 64 bit processor?  How much memory does your computer have?

Answer (score 3):

Try installing JDK then launch VS and go to
Tools -> Xamarin -> Android Settings and under "Java Development Kit Location" press change and select ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_131 instead of ProgramFiles(x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_131

I dont know if it will work for everyone, i am not very experienced but it worked for me

Comment: Thanks, Will neeh.
But I had upgrade to 64-bit Win10 to solved the problem, and it works now.